# RSS feed for posts I have asked or answered

Tags: discussion, feed

I would like RSS feeds for all the posts which I have asked or answered?

In my profile page, at bottom, there is a "User Feed", but that shows me everything including my comments. I want specifically only my questions, answers and favorites.

Comment: Try the "user feed" link at the bottom right of your profile.

Comment: @animuson: thanks. But show me everything including my comments also. i want specific only questions/ answer/favourite

Comment: [Stack2RSS - A JSON to RSS Conversion Service \[Now Fully Open Source!\]](http://stackapps.com/q/1599)